# C# Oracle OracleDataReader.Read()

Tags: c#, database, oracle, plsql

I've ran into a little problem with my Oracle and C#. When I'm running this query it returns 0 rows, so rd.Read() = false. But it's weird, because there are records in the database. Running the exact same query in SQL Developer returns 2 rows.

I'm running Oracle XE 11.2

Can anyone maybe explain why dr.Read() returns false?

EDIT: Connecting to the database works 100%.

```
    public List<ChatMessage> ReceiveMessage(string account_ID, string account_ID2)
    {
        //Initialize list of strings for all the messages
        List<ChatMessage> list = new List<ChatMessage>();

        //Make connection
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connstring);
        con.Open();

        //Make query
        string query = "SELECT Sender_ID, Receiver_ID, Message, Msg_Date FROM TBL_CHAT WHERE Sender_ID = '1' AND Receiver_ID = '2' OR Sender_ID = '2' AND Receiver_ID = '1' ORDER BY Msg_Date DESC";

        //Add parameters
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        //cmd.Parameters.Add("account_ID", account_ID);
        //cmd.Parameters.Add("account_ID2", account_ID2);

        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = query;

        //Execute query and initialize reader
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //Start reading the messages and add them to a list
        while(dr.Read())
        {
            string sender_ID = dr.GetString(0);
            string receiver_ID = dr.GetString(1);
            string message = dr.GetString(2);
            DateTime date = dr.GetDateTime(3);

            ChatMessage msg = new ChatMessage(message, sender_ID, receiver_ID, date);
            list.Add(msg);
        }

        //Close database
        con.Close();

        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Have you ever debug your code and see your `dr` has _really_ 2 rows?

Comment: Uncommitted transaction?

Comment: dr returns 0 rows. That's the problem.

Comment: @Guido Are you sure your `.._ID` columns are character typed? Looks like they should be numerical based on their names.

Comment: Try remove `WHERE` from the SQL and see if table contains any record. If it does, check `WHERE`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Hi, already tried this and it still returns 0 rows.

Comment: @SonerGönül Hi, already tried this as well and it didn't work.

Comment: @Guido: then check in any *Sql Editor* if `TBL_CHAT` is an *empty* table.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko it isn't... I checked it in SQL DEVELOPER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error,

There was no commit statement in the CREATE script of the database.
After putting this in it worked.

Comment: This is confusing then how did it work using sqldeveloper, you can only see uncommitted data in a given session, else for all other session its not existing unless committed

Comment: This is the behavior of transaction irrespective of the database, so a new learning :)